# Django Rest Framework M2M Through Model field not resolving

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here are my models

```
# Models
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, related_name="children")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    alternate_naming = models.ManyToManyField('businesses.Office', through='CategoryOfficeNaming', blank=True)


class CategoryOfficeNaming(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    office = models.ForeignKey('businesses.Office')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

And here are my serializers

```
# Serializers
class CategoryOfficeNamingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CategoryOfficeNaming
        fields = (
            'office',
            'name',
        )


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # We need special recursive serialization here for Category (parent) -> Category (child) relationship
    children = serializers.ListSerializer(read_only=True, child=RecursiveField())
    alternate_naming = CategoryOfficeNamingSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'children',
            'name',
            'alternate_naming',
        )
```

I get an error when trying serialize a Category:

```
AttributeError at /api/categories/
'Office' object has no attribute 'category'
```

It seems like the Serializer (alternate_naming) points to an Office instance instead of using the through model (CategoryOfficeNaming) -- why is that? I'm probably doing something silly!

Answer (score 0):

A, ha!

It turns out I was misunderstanding when to use through tables a bit. Instead of using a through table, I ended up with this structure and I got something that works for this situation:

Models:

```
# Models
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, related_name="children")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class CategoryOfficeNaming(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name="alternate_namings")
    office = models.ForeignKey('businesses.Office')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Serializers:

```
# Serializers
class CategoryOfficeNamingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CategoryOfficeNaming
        fields = (
            'office',
            'name',
        )


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # We need special recursive serialization here for Category (parent) -> Category (child) relationship
    children = serializers.ListSerializer(read_only=True, child=RecursiveField())
    alternate_namings = CategoryOfficeNamingSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'children',
            'name',
            'alternate_namings',
        )
```